# Poison a blocking queue when the queue type contains a generic

Tags: java

I have a type, `MyType<T>` that contains a generic type `T`. I have a blocking queue of type `BlockingQueue<MyType<T>>`. I would like to send "end-of-stream" markers to the queue, i.e. poison pills, but the issue is that I cannot instantiated a poison pill because of the generic type. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just create one.

```
class MyType<T> {


    private BlockingQueue<MyType<T>> q = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10);
    // Poison pill to signal the end of the queue.
    public static final MyType<?> PILL = new MyType<>();

    /**
     * Special private constructor for PILL creation.
     */
    private MyType() {

    }

    public boolean queueClosed() {
        return q.peek() == PILL;
    }
}
```

If you have your own constructors you could add a `private` constructor with no parameters.

Comment: That doesn't work because there is no guarantee on the constructor. Also, storing an empty object inside each instance of MyType is inefficient.

Comment: @Max - I noticed mine wasn't `static` - fixed that. Better?

Answer (score 1):

You can still create the generic object and just cast it. For example look at java.util.Collections.emptyList():

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static final List EMPTY_LIST = new EmptyList<Object>();

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static final <T> List<T>  emptyList() {
    return (List<T>) EMPTY_LIST;
}
```

Just make sure that the end-of-stream marker handling doesn't use/depend on

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it is difficult to find the right solution. What I can think of is:

- Add a method to `MyType` that signals that this is the poison pill.
- Create an empty `PoisonPill` marker interface, and add a `getPoison()` static method to `MyType` that returns a `MyType implements PoisonPill` and then test using `instanceof`.